# Disable find&replace for some sentences in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a large document that has key points about certain topics and subject. I want to be able to use the 'find' feature to locate certain words, but since there any many of the same words that I'm searching for, I have to click next until I get to the right part. Is there anyway that I can disable this feature for some of the words, as I want to have a fast way to search for a topic without having to click next fifty times.

Comment: Add more words to the search function.

Comment: In Word 2010, the third tab of the Navigation Pane will show all occurrences of the found text, which you can scroll down to the occurrence you want. If the Navigation Pane is not visible, you can turn it on by check-marking "Navigation Pane" in the Show section of the Insert tab on the ribbon. (PS: The closest you could get to what you've specifically asked for is a VBA routine to loop through to the nth occurrence of the search term.)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to combine Find with groupings in a Document Map. Say each page was a different level in the Map then start with PageX, use Find and, when you want to race forward, instead of clicking through all instances jump to the next section (select PageX+1 via the Document Map) and continue with Find.